# Calculating the average of multiple entries with identical names

Tags: r, dataframe, average

Not sure if the title makes sense, but I am new to "R" and to say the least I am confused. As you can see in the code below I have multiple entries that have the same name. For example, time ON and sample 1 appears 3 times. I want to figure out how to calculate the average of the OD at time ON and sample 1. How do I go about doing this? I want to do this for all repeats in the data frame.

Thanks in advance! Hope my question makes sense.

```
> freednaod
   time sample    OD
1    ON      1 0.248
2    ON      1 0.245
3    ON      1 0.224
4    ON      2 0.262
5    ON      2 0.260
6    ON      2 0.255
7    ON      3 0.245
8    ON      3 0.249
9    ON      3 0.244
10    0      1 0.010
11    0      1 0.013
12    0      1 0.012
13    0      2 0.014
14    0      2 0.013
15    0      2 0.015
16    0      3 0.013
17    0      3 0.013
18    0      3 0.014
19   30      1 0.018
20   30      1 0.020
21   30      1 0.019
22   30      2 0.017
23   30      2 0.019
24   30      2 0.021
25   30      3 0.021
26   30      3 0.020
27   30      3 0.024
28   60      1 0.023
29   60      1 0.024
30   60      1 0.023
31   60      2 0.031
32   60      2 0.031
33   60      2 0.033
34   60      3 0.025
35   60      3 0.028
36   60      3 0.024
37   90      1 0.052
38   90      1 0.048
39   90      1 0.049
40   90      2 0.076
41   90      2 0.078
42   90      2 0.081
43   90      3 0.073
44   90      3 0.068
45   90      3 0.067
46  120      1 0.124
47  120      1 0.128
48  120      1 0.134
49  120      2 0.202
50  120      2 0.202
51  120      2 0.186
52  120      3 0.192
53  120      3 0.182
54  120      3 0.183
55  150      1 0.229
56  150      1 0.215
57  150      1 0.220
58  150      2 0.197
59  150      2 0.216
60  150      2 0.200
61  150      3 0.207
62  150      3 0.211
63  150      3 0.209
```

Comment: Try `aggregate(OD ~ ., freednaod, mean)`

Comment: Thanks! 
Now my data frame is not organized by time, how can I re-order my data frame so that it can be organized by time?

Comment: I posted my comment as a solution with the changes you wanted

Answer (score 0):

By converting the 'time' column to a `factor` with `levels` specified by the `unique` level, the output would be ordered in the same order as in the initial dataset

```
aggregate(OD~ sample + time, transform(freednaod, 
         time = factor(time, levels = unique(time))), mean)[c(2, 1, 3)]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
freednaod %>%
   group_by(time = factor(time, levels = unique(time)), sample) %>%  
   summarise(OD = mean(OD))
```